# SSL and redirects security

Tags: tls

I have a domain, let say:

```
example.com
```

I also have a domain

```
server.example.com
```

which points to my Elastic Beanstalk.

I've written some rule, that redirects certain traffic from example.com to server.example.com (thus my Elastic Beanstalk):

```
example.com -> server.example.com -> elasticbeanstalk
```

Now, on my example.com I've got a wildcard SSL (*.example.com, is active on both example.com and server.example.com).

I've also updated that certificate to the Elastic Beanstalk loader.

Now, I am wondering If this set up is secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **client** redirect : If all domains use https **AND** HSTS, then the redirect is  as safe as possible.

For server "proxy": If they are on the same server http is probably fine. If they are in the same internal network, http is not a good idea. If internet is between them, http is not safe at all. For https, make sure the servers check the validity of the certificates.

Comment: What would be the case, if elasticbeanstalk wouldn't have installed SSL?

Comment: If they are on the same server it's probably fine. If they are in the same internal network, not really good. If internet is between them, not safe at all.

Comment: sorry for bother - last follow up question. What if the traffic between example.com and server.example.com goes via http?

Comment: @uksz the same. I've updated the answer. TL;DR: always use https (except for communication inside the same server)

Answer (score 1):

The security of the setup depends on the unknown security of the different sites. The redirect by itself does not add any security or insecurity.
 The sharing of the same certificate between different sites might add some insecurity if these sites are served by different hosts which thus all need to have the same private key installed. This increases the risk of compromise since it the chance is higher that one of several hosts has a security problem than only a single host.

Comment: **The redirect/proxy do add insecurity** if not encrypted and sent over the network!

Comment: @Tom: exactly. But **this is not a problem of the redirect but of the original security of the sites**. If the sites are only available with HTTPS the redirects will be HTTPS too. If the sites are available with HTTP the HTTP redirect does not make it less secure than it already is. It is not possible to do a HTTP only redirect to/from sites which do only HTTPS. That's why I said it depends on the unknown security of the sites.

Comment: Yes, but if done not carefully, the redirect may decrease security, for example if the target use http and https but the redirect use http, or or the redirect use https but do not check the certificate.

Comment: @Tom: certificate validation is unrelated to redirect. The validation is done by the browser for every access to the site and not only if the access was caused by a redirect. Skipping the validation is therefore not a problem related to the redirect. If the target offers http and https then again it is a problem of the original site which might be highlighted by a redirect but also by any direct access to the site.

Comment: By "redirect" I think @uksh means "proxy" or back-end redirect. But even with "browser redirect" it may be less secure to redirect: if you redirect to http://example.com , even if example.com use https and redirect http to https, it's less secure, you should redirect directly to the https version. It's one example of what can go wrong.

Comment: @Tom: if the site is available through HTTP then redirect is just one of the many kinds of access to this site which expose information. The problem is not the redirect but that the site is available with HTTP. Do you mean with "back-end redirect" a *forward* by a proxy? I think this is usually not called  redirect but proxy forward so I don't think that the OP is asking about this.

Comment: Yes, I meant forward proxy, I think he may ask about that for "server.example.com -> elasticbeanstalk" but I'm not sure